# How to do dimension reduction from a variational autoencoder

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders

I am thinking about a variational autoencoder. As far as I understand it, in the encoding section you compress to a `px1` tensor and then you create a $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of dimensions of my choice (though less than $p$). The decoding layer is then the reverse.

But what if I want to do dimensionality reduction using the VAE? Clearly I don't randomly sample from $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Do I just go to the px1 tensor?

Thanks!

Comment: From what you're describing, you'd likely be better suited by a plain (non-variational) autoencoder.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check [this example](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/) from the Keras docs and see what you get at the output of the encoder. At the end of the page you can see a representation of the 2 dimensional latent space of the architecture that is defined previously in that article. Plus you can check [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.11060.pdf) about using VAEs for time series dimensionality reduction and feature extraction.